# Use num keyboard as arrow keys in Android Studio

Tags: keyboard, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to use the num keyboard in android studio (linux version) as the arrow keys. This is what I'm used in windows and it is really annoying for me not to be able to do it on ubuntu. When bloq num is off and I press 8,4,2 or 6 keys on the num keyb nothing happen. It should move the caret towards the correct direction.

Is there anyway to make this working?

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can. It may not be the most brilliant solution, but it works:

1) `File->Settings->Keymap`

2) Search for down (for example) in the edit box at the top

3) You'll see there's already a Down arrow key assigned to it. Right click on it and select "Add keyboard shortcut"

4) A dialog appears. Press the down arrow key on the numeric keypad and press Ok.

Voila, now your down arrow key will work.
Do that for all the rest of the arrow keys

Comment: Doesn't work as the Keymapper recognises the keypad "down" as "down"

Comment: It worked for me in Android Studio 2.1.2 on Ubuntu, but before adding a new shortcut, make sure to delete the existing one first. Of course, now it will  work on the num pad only.

Comment: The dialog displays keypad-down as "Down" but internally it must be different, because it does change the key's action.

Answer (score 3):

For those on Linux you can use `xmodmap` tool to remap the scan codes from the numpad from `KP_Up` to `Up` etc to see the scan code you use another tool `xev` in my case I'll I have to do is

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 80 = Up"
xmodmap -e "keycode 88 = Down"
xmodmap -e "keycode 83 = Left"
xmodmap -e "keycode 85 = Right"
```

your scan codes may be different and you don't need root for any of this :)

Answer (score 1):

Please vote this issue up (click star) in the google issue list:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=90939